# How do I use the "where" parameter to add the picture at the end of an array?

Tags: java

This method is supposed to insert the picture at the position given by the `where` parameter value.

I am confuse on how to use the `where` parameter.

This is what I have so far:

```
public boolean addPicture( Picture thePicture, int where )
{
    int index = where; 
    while( index < pictArray.length )
    {
        pictArray[pictArray.length - 1] = thePicture;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: if where is the index, then assignment statement should be pictArray[index] = thePicture;

Comment: @Waqas don't you think it should be index-1 :)

Comment: @IshanKhanna well if where is based on 0-index then it won't otherwise it will- but after seeing the code it seems like where is 0-based

Comment: array index is starting from 0

Answer (score 0):

If you already know where to add the Picture, Just add it to that position on the Picture array Index-1 position. This is because Indexing in java Starts with a 0.But we as humans start it from 1.

Like if it is to be added on the 3rd position according to the user. He inputs 3 in the Where variable. Java will have to store it on the index 2 of the array.

```
PicArray[index-1]=picture;
```